# Estructura de directorios de Laravel

Tags: laravel

Estoy analizando la [estructura de directorios que trae Laravel tras su instalación](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/structure)
y su "evolución" basada en la documentación oficial, convenciones y prácticas recomendadas.

Estoy mirando la de Laravel 7, que es la versión con la que estoy trabajando hoy.
En la documentación no aparece la estructura completa o "profunda" que es lo que estoy buscando.
Por ejemplo, aparece un [listado de directorios de la carpeta raíz](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/structure#the-root-directory)
y de [directorios del directorio "app"](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/structure#the-app-directory),
pero no de los directorios contenidos en "Http".

Por ***evolución de la estructura*** me refiero a los directorios que se añaden habitualmente,
cuando el proyecto se va desarrollando,
por ejemplo, "app/Helpers/" o "app/Models/", que se elimino en la version 5 y ha vuelto con la 8,
porque en la práctica, casi todos seguían usando. O directorios como "app/Views/"
cuya creación se "recomienda" cuando añadimos *View Composers*, *Components*, etc.

**Entonces, ¿conocen ejemplos más completos de la estructura de directorios de Laravel?**

> Editado

Lo que sé, por el momento sobre la estructura de directorios de Laravel está en esta [entrada de mi blog](https://www.ironwoods.es/blog/laravel/estructura-directorios), salvo excepciones todos lo directorios que indico son los propios de Laravel, los que trae al inicio y los que se van creando, normalmente vía comandos con *artisan*. Algunos se mencionan en la documentación o ya los conocía, otros los descubrí al ejecutar cada opción de `artisan make`.

Comment: La [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/structure#the-http-directory) misma muestra lo que usualmente va en `Http`.

Comment: Vengo siguiendo [este proyecto](https://github.com/guillaumebriday/laravel-blog) desde hace unos años, como ejemplos de estudio de las características de laravel. Creo que cumple con su propósito. Ahora, para ver la evolución, tendrás que revisar los commits. No se bien que respuesta esperas obtener, explicar toda esa estructura sería como explicar cada característica que se fue agregando, y el por qué se la implementó de esa manera.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ ese proyecto tiene una estructura bastante "normal", sólo vi como añadido "app/Concern" con un *trait*. Yo a veces he añadido un directorio "app/Traits" o "app/CMS" para eso... me interesa saber si es habitual o esta recomendado en la propia doc de Laravel por ejemplo, crear "app/Traits" o ya cada uno hace lo que considera. Escribí una entrada: https://www.ironwoods.es/blog/laravel/estructura-directorios sobre la estructura de directorios de Laravel, la de inicio y como va creciendo, que es lo que me interesa, *donde poner cada cosa cuando empezamos a hacer "añadidos"*.